# How to get height of ScrollView with a lot of child elements?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there any way to get height of whole ScrollView element in React Native?

```
return (
  <View ref='container' style={[ styles.container, backgroundColor, {width: this.props.width} ]}>
    <ScrollView ref='scroll' style={styles.scrollView}>  --> what height with inner content?
      {this._getTitle()}
      <View style={styles.content}>
        {items}
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.empty]} />
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
)
```

Comment: are you asking about the height or the content size of the scroll-view? The height is usually fixed, and content size changes as children are added to the scroll container.

Comment: I want to receive height of scrollView with the content added to it @Artal

Comment: again, the height is fixed. For example: your scroll-view can take up the whole screen. But the content is not the same, can be lower, or it can be higher (at this point you have scrolling of the content to reach it all). Please be clear if you want to check the height or the content size, these are two different things.

Comment: ok, how to get content size in pixels?

Comment: see my answer, don't know if this is exactly what you're after but maybe it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is an officially documented API, but getting the content size can be done using the native scroll-view manager.

Add the necessary imports:

```
import ReactNative, {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
const ScrollViewManager = NativeModules.ScrollViewManager;
```

Call this in your code at a point where you already have access to the scrollview ref:

```
if(ScrollViewManager && ScrollViewManager.getContentSize) {
  ScrollViewManager.getContentSize(ReactNative.findNodeHandle(this.scrollViewRef), (contentSize) => {
    console.log(contentSize);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped